# A PDE involving a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, symmetry

This question is a special case of this [one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391623/does-this-geometric-pde-have-a-solution).

Let $s(\theta)>0, b(\theta)$ be two smooth **non-constant** real-valued functions on $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Do there exist a diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ and a **non-constant** function $g:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\phi'(\theta)=\frac{s(\theta)}{s(\phi(\theta)+g(r))}, \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\big(\phi'(\theta)\big)^2+ 1/\big(\phi'(\theta)\big)^2+\big(rg'(r)+b \big( \phi(\theta)+g(r) \big)-b(\theta)\cdot \phi'(\theta)\big)^2/s^2(\theta)=C>2 \tag{2}
$$
is independent of $r,\theta$?

---

$\phi=\text{Id}$ does not satisfy this. Equation $(1)$ reduces to
$$
1=\frac{s(\theta)}{s(\theta+g(r))}, \tag{1'}
$$
and Equation $(2)$ reduces to
$$
rg'(r)+b \big( \theta+g(r) \big)-b(\theta)=\sqrt{C-2}s(\theta). \tag{2'}
$$
Integrating over $\theta$ and using the periodicity of $b$ (as a function over $\mathbb{S}^1$), we get
$$
2\pi rg'(r)=\sqrt{C-2}\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}s(\theta) \tag{3},
$$
so $g'(r)=\frac{c}{r}$, and $g(r)=c \log r+c_0$.

Plugging this into Equation $(1')$ we deduce that $s$ is a constant function, contradicting the assumption.